# What is appropriate usage of words loggia, deck, patio, balcony and so on

Tags: word-usage

As part of my assignment I need to describe details of Thomas Kinkade's artwork [Silent Night](http://www.thomaskinkade.com/magi/servlet/com.asucon.ebiz.catalog.web.tk.CatalogServlet?catalogAction=Product&productId=325&menuNdx=0).
I can't find how is the left part of the cabin called (part where you can see Christmas Tree).

I have several options:

- patio
- balcony
- deck
- verandah
- porch
- loggia (as for me, it seems like most appropriate)

but I'm not sure that at least one of them has suitable meaning.

What is appropriate word for this?

Comment: I personally would go with *balcony*. *Deck* would be the least likely choice for me, for it must have no roof. But architectural structure is not my domain. :)

Comment: Why do you believe "loggia" fits the best? To me, it's the farthest off: a loggia must have columns and arches, otherwise it's just a porch.

Comment: @Martha actually, that was just an assumption.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All of the terms listed in the question refer either to architectural features which are partly or wholly outdoors.

The area of the cabin in the picture, with the Christmas tree inside it, is part of a room, and is entirely inside the cabin.

So a couple of suggestions:

**[Bay window](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bay_window)**:

> A bay window is a window space projecting outward from the main walls of a building and forming a bay in a room.

**[Sunroom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunroom)** or **solarium**:

> A sunroom, sun parlor, sun porch, or sun lounge is a structure usually constructed onto the side of a house which allows enjoyment of the surrounding landscape while being sheltered from adverse weather conditions such as rain and wind.

Comment: What Steve said: all of your suggestions are open to the elements. You need something that implies enclosure.

Comment: I'd go with "sunroom" I think, but another option is "enclosed porch". That's something of an oxymoron, as a porch is normally understood to be open, but it's a term in fairly common use.

Comment: In many parts of the US, a *porch* can be enclosed. Typically they're initially built open to the elements, then enclosed with screens or windows, but the owners/users continue to call the enclosed space a porch.

Comment: +1 I'd go with "sunroom" here. @ThePhoton is quite right about enclosed porches, but this lit space in the painting looks to me more like an extension of the room than a porch, which even when enclosed communicates with the interior by a door.

Comment: @StoneyB, to me the idea of a sunroom conveys modernity, while a porch conveys rusticity. I think porch therefore fits better the intent of the painting. But the architecture shown is really more fanciful than truly old, and the construction does look more like a sunroom than a porch.

Comment: @ThePhoton Yes, it's not genuinely "rustic". My objection to *porch* is my feeling (which is perhaps too nicely etymological) that a porch must be a structure around a door.

Comment: +1 for sunroom,  -1 for bay window.

Comment: It doesn't look big enough to me to be a whole room. I'd call it a bay window.

Comment: @TRiG - Funny; I'd say it looks too big to be a bay window, so I'd call it a sunroom. (When I hear "bay window," I imagine something more like [this](http://www.martinocompanies.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/baywindow.jpeg), which is clearly much smaller than the room in the Kinkade picture. On the other hand, you could put up a Christmas tree in [this sunroom](http://ae-i.com/sun-rooms-2331x1920-sunrooms-porches-amp-more-what39s-new-in-home-exterior-remodeling/).)

Answer (score 4):

The structure I see looks exactly like my sunroom, (or [solarium](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+solarium&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a)): a room fitted with extensive areas of glass to admit sunlight.

[image]